# How to read & update data in the Sql ce database located in Windows phone app data folder?

Tags: windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

I have placed the SQL CE Database file in the installation folder of the Windows phone application.i want to perform Read and Write operations on the database but it was saying Access to the database file is not allowed.
Please suggest me how can i achieve this

Comment: Was the db file created by phone app or just copied? Are you able to perform read?

Comment: @StephenZeng i have copied the Db(External created .sdf file).No,i was unable to read the data from the database.it is saying access to the database file is not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the database to isolated storage on first run, as the installation folder is read-only. You will also need to change the connection string:

```
data source=isostore://mydb.sdf
```

See much more in my blog post here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/04/generate-windows-phone-8-local-database.html